# Need to write a php script that will display value near to user entered value

Tags: php

I want to write a script that can give me value which is not accurate but is close to user entered value. For example: It is like string comparison. Comparing characters of user query.

Data is stored on SQL. For example:

```
$string1="Where were you";
$string2="where ere youuu";
```

`$string1` is value stored in database.

`$string 2` is user value.

It should return output like this:

```
where were you
```

I do have this but it is not working fine for me:

```
$a = "hello where are you"; 
$b = "hell re r u"; $str = "";

for ($i=0; $i < strlen($a); $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < strlen($b); $j++) { 
        if ($a[$i]==$b[$j]) {
            $str.=$a[$i];
            break;
        }
     }
 } 
 echo $str;
```

It's not giving desired results.

Comment: There are a variety of approaches to this, such as various string comparison algorithms to determine the "distance" between two strings, or the use of things like "soundex" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

Comment: How do you define an "accurate result"? This isn't a trivial thing to do.

Comment: I think what you want is a very serious search logic and for sure it won't happen with two `for` cycles. Try searching Google for some kind of full text search implementations. Give us some more details. If data is on SQL server try splitting the string in chunks and do a `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with a similar problem where user input could have spelling mistakes and partial words.

I tried using soundex function of PHP but in my experience it results in a lot of false positives. Then I tried the metaphone function and it worked far better than soundex. Then there is also the levenshtein function which calculates distances between two strings, which gives you the number of characters you have to add, remove or change in order to get one string from another. You could use a combination of these to get more accurate results.

However, reaching 100% accuracy is, as far as I know, not possible for all user inputs. For some user inputs, you could provide a 100% accurate result, and for others, you could provide the user options to select from.

Reference pages: [soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php), [metaphone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) and [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)